# Open google and search for text with speech recognition

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I'm writing a code to search on google by voice recognition, I would like to open the results in a second form. 
this is the code in my first form

```
namespace Jarvis
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string Temperature;
        string Condition;
        string Humidity;
        string WindSpeed;
        string Town;
        string TFCond;
        string TFHigh;
        string TFLow;

        Boolean wake = true;

        private void StopWindow()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process[] procs = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcWindow);
            foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process proc in procs)
            {
                proc.CloseMainWindow();

            }
        }

        // Weather application from Yahoo
        // to change city go to woeid on google, on yahoo site, type city take the code and past it below behind http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=
        private void GetWeather()
        {
            string query = String.Format("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=973688");
            XmlDocument wData = new XmlDocument();
            wData.Load(query);

            // go to the link http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w= and copy the http on top of the page
            XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(wData.NameTable);
            manager.AddNamespace("yweather", "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0");

            XmlNode channel = wData.SelectSingleNode("rss").SelectSingleNode("channel");
            XmlNodeList nodes = wData.SelectNodes("/rss/channel/item/yweather:forecast", manager);

            Temperature = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectSingleNode("yweather:condition", manager).Attributes["temp"].Value;

            Condition = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectSingleNode("yweather:condition", manager).Attributes["text"].Value;

            Humidity = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:atmosphere", manager).Attributes["humidity"].Value;

            WindSpeed = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:wind", manager).Attributes["speed"].Value;

            Town = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:location", manager).Attributes["city"].Value;

            TFCond = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectSingleNode("yweather:forecast", manager).Attributes["text"].Value;

            TFHigh = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectSingleNode("yweather:forecast", manager).Attributes["high"].Value;

            TFLow = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectSingleNode("yweather:forecast", manager).Attributes["low"].Value;
        }

        SpeechRecognitionEngine rec = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        SpeechSynthesizer s = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        int count = 1;
        Choices list = new Choices();
        string ProcWindow;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ///  line under writes the program commands to the DIR 
            ///  all commands are without capital lettres


            list.Add(new string[] { "good morning jarvis", "good afternoon jarvis", "good evening jarvis" });

            list.Add(new string[] { "how are you", "how are you feeling", "how was your day" });

            list.Add(new string[] { "what time is it", "whats the time", "how late is it" });

            list.Add(new string[] { "what is today", "whats the date of today" });

            // web browser
            list.Add(new string[] { "open google", "open facebook", "open youtube", "open chrome", "open gmail", "open hotmail" });

            // programs
            list.Add(new string[] { "start wordpad", "close wordpad", "start word", "close word", "start excel", "close excel", "start visual studio", "close visual studio", "start inventor", "close inventor", "start solidworks", "close solidworks", "start word", "close word", "start matlab", "close matlab" });

            list.Add(new string[] { "jarvis mute", "jarvis wake", "jarvis search for" });

            // weather prediction

            list.Add(new string[] { "whats tommorrows forecast", "how is the weather" });

            Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(list));

            try
            {
                rec.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
                rec.LoadGrammar(gr);
                rec.SpeechRecognized += rec_SpeechRecognized;
                rec.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice(); // sets to earplugs of speakers
                rec.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
                // Set the speaking rate and volume
                s.Rate = -1;
                s.Volume = 100;
            }

            catch { return; }

            // Change voice Female, Male
            s.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Neutral);

            s.Speak("I am active and online sir!");
        }

        public static void killProg(string s)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process[] Procs = null;

            try
            {
                Procs = Process.GetProcessesByName(s);
                Process prog = Procs[0];

                if (!prog.HasExited)
                {
                    prog.Kill();

                }
            }

            finally
            {
                if (Procs != null)
                {
                    foreach (Process p in Procs)
                    {
                        p.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void say(string h)
        {
            s.Speak(h);
        }

        private void rec_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            string r = e.Result.Text;

            if (r == "jarvis wake") wake = true;
            if (r == "jarvis mute") wake = false;

            if (r.ToLower().Contains("jarvis search for")) // See if the string contains the 'search for' string.
            {
                var googleGrammar = new DictationGrammar();
                    rec.LoadGrammarAsync(googleGrammar);
                Google searching = new Google();

                searching.password = r;
                searching.ShowDialog();

                return;
            }
```

Here  I ask jarvis search for "something"
then he should open the second form with the following code

```
public partial class Google : Form
    {
        private string searchWord;

        public string password
        {
            get { return searchWord; }
            set { searchWord = Text; }
        }

        public Google()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Google_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            searchBox.Text = searchWord;

            string search = searchBox.Text;

            StringBuilder add = new StringBuilder("https://www.google.com/#q=");
            add.Append(searchWord);

            googleWebbrowser.Navigate(add.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is:

Now when I say jarvis search for "something" the second form opens and I push the button it searches for Form2 and not that "something" I'm asking

Answer (score 1):

```
set {searchWord = value;}
```

Not "= Text;}

Also, you are setting password to r, which seems to be the entire voice command and not just the target search object (Ie. r = "Search for something" and not just "something").

Comment: thanks, one problem solved. and indeed, any Idea how to solve this isue?

Comment: Which problem was solved?  Which still needs resolution?  Did you make the code change for the "set"?

Comment: oh Sorry, the set code was solved. know when I say jarvis search for water. Jarvis doesn't start to search. when I say only jarvis search for it starts to search. I think it is a problem with the if statement? if (r.ToLower().Contains("jarvis search for"))

Comment: Add a breakline to the if statement and check the value of r at runtime.

Comment: Also, could you post up your code leading up to the if statement?

Comment: I will edit the code in my question because it's quite long. I allready added a return. this doesn't help

Comment: Looking at the entire code now, I suspect that the reason the "jarvis search for something" isn't working is because the "something" isn't part of the grammar.  Meaning, once you add that word to the phrase "jarvis search for" the phrase is no longer matched in the grammar list.  I don't know much about speech recognition grammar, but you could try to separate the commands (i.e "jarvis search") then prompt the user  "search for what."  Just a thought.  I will fiddle with this to see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Okay, I've loaded up your code and tested a few things.  I've confirmed that the issues are with your grammar.  When I say "Jarvis Search for cars," most of the time, it stops recognizing me at "for" and ignores cars.  If you can get your grammar rules defined and parse out the trigger phrase from the search parameters, you will have it working.  Seems to work decently, if you don't mind repeating yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As for your issue with parsing the search word from the phrase... I've tested this modification to your speechRecongized method.

```
        private void rec_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            string r = e.Result.Text.ToLower();

            if (r == "jarvis wake") wake = true;
            if (r == "jarvis mute") wake = false;

            if (r.Contains("jarvis search for")) // See if the string contains the 'search for' string.
            {
                var googleGrammar = new DictationGrammar();
                rec.LoadGrammarAsync(googleGrammar);
                Google searching = new Google();
                int indexOfSearchWords = r.IndexOf("jarvis search for") + 17; // 17 is length of "jarvis search for" +1
                r = r.Substring(indexOfSearchWords, r.Length - indexOfSearchWords); //sets r to everything in the phrase after "jarvis search for"

                if (r!="")
                {
                    searching.password = r;
                    searching.Google_ShowSearchWord();
                    searching.ShowDialog();
                }

                return;
            }
        }
```

I've noticed that the first time you say "jarvis search for cars," it stops at "jarvis search for", but if you leave the program running and say it again, it will recognize the entire phrase correctly.  I think this is because the way you are adding the grammer on the first iteration.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code, but it's still not working for me. now I first got an error for searching.Google_ShowSearchWord(); 
'Google' does not contain a definition for 'Google_ShowSearchWord' and no extension method 'Google_ShowSearchWord' accepting a first argument of type 'Google' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) When I remove this (I don't think it's necessary in the code?) then Jarvis doesn't respons anymore on the question jarvis search for.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot I added a function on the google search form called ShowSearchWord, that sets the searchBox text to the phase to be searched.

Comment: oke, but it's still not working. the program runs until if (r!=""). then it just doesn't do anything anymore

Answer (score 0):

**The answers above will cause your program to hang.** It's a terrible solution to be frank, and I'm surprised this was never mentioned by others.
I noticed you aren't using a switch case as well with your **rec_SpeechRecognized Sub**. It's not a must but a much smarter approach because they are faster in most cases verse **If Statements**

**Note**: This depends on whether the number of conditions are large for switch case. I have a solution you can try and you don't need to add commands to a text file, but it does require a text file added.  I use **StringBuilder** with **AppendLine** to orchestrate my speech. It will constantly update your text file, overwriting your last search and the execution is fast without needing to repeat yourself. Given it's design, it is best to use it on another form however, devoted primarily for searches, but that is your decision to make. When you aren't using it you could create a command that says: **"End now"** with a  **SendKeys.Send("%{F4}");** to terminate the form or **Application.Exit**. **This is a hybrid approach** and it will detect phrases easily and again, you won't have to dedicate your efforts to a hours of adding to a command list. This uses **DictationGrammar** as you have. I converted the code for you, because mine was in VB.Net.
**Below is the code in an image file and a link to my GitHub repository**

Answer (score 0):

Just click the image to blow it up. I had converted the code, but this site makes it difficult posting code most of the time so I stick with images & links. Saves a headache...

[This is my code in VB.Net](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQcd2.png)

My repository is here with the code to offer full detail: https://github.com/Rythorian77/Dictation-Hybrid/commit/7a9b5697b67b46d9018525ea33beb1bacad1f949

You can convert this at: https://converter.telerik.com